# How to insert hundreds of rows in a table, without facing resource limit reach error?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of students, also a table of invoices. I want to insert a (invoice) row against every student equal to their fee.

I do this job using this code:

```
$sql = "select * from students'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $studentID = $row['st_id'];
    $fee = $row['fee'];

    // /create invoice code::
    $accountID = 0;
    $description = "Monthly Fee For" . date('F-Y');
    $amount = $fee;
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $status = 0;
    $query2 = "insert into invoices (account_id, invoice_desc, invoice_date, invoice_amount, invoice_status, student_id) values ('$accountID','$description','$date','$amount','$status','$studentID')";
    if (mysql_query($query2))
        echo "Done!!!";
    else
        die(mysql_error());
};
```

Using this loop on localhost it works fine. But live server it does not work and shows instead:

> 508 error resource limit is reached

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: How long does the script take before you get the 508 error? This seems like an Apache issue, not MySQL. (Aside: please try not to write questions all in lower case. We want posts here to be as tidy and readable as possible).

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if it would be better to rewrite this in MySQL - you can do a `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, which should be significantly quicker. Your column changes (e.g. descript) can be done in MySQL too.

Comment: i think more than 30 seconds it was taking. after this error i see invoice table, this query insert just 10-15 rows.

Comment: Thank you! i will try this query live and then will tell you.

Comment: Can you paste your php_info() and your apache logs after you get this error?

Comment: 15 rows inserted in 30 seconds! That sounds like your database server is completely inadequate, or completely overloaded. Unless you have millions of rows, I'd expect "hundreds" of rows to be inserted individually using PHP in a second or so. Are you on a shared host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query2 = "
    insert into invoices
    (student_id, invoice_amount, invoice_date, invoice_status, invoice_desc)
    select st_id, (fee - scholarships), '$date', '$status', '$description' from students
";
```

By using `insert into ...select` statement I have fixed this issue :)

Comment: Great. Don't forget to accept your own answer - click the tick mark to the left, so it turns green.

Comment: And make sure none of these values come from user input, otherwise you'll have an SQL injection vuln to deal with.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried a bulk insert instead of looping and inserting each time?

```
INSERT INTO
    MY_TABLE(column1,column,column3)
VALUES
    //loop query1 results to build values
    (val1a,val2a,val3a),
    (val1b,val2b,val3b),
    (val1c,val2c,val3c)
    etc…
```